# PHP Context Error

Tags: php, symfony

I have an error, see an image of it [here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh0qM.png)

But my class is defined as:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
```

and here is the constructor of class `OAuthStorage`:

```
public function __construct(ClientManagerInterface $clientManager, AccessTokenManagerInterface $accessTokenManager,
    RefreshTokenManagerInterface $refreshTokenManager, AuthCodeManagerInterface $authCodeManager,
    UserProviderInterface $userProvider = null, EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory = null)
```

Why does PHP give me an error? `UserRepository` implements `UserProviderInterface` ...

Comment: You should show how you call this constructor

Comment: Your User entity is not properly mapped to your UserRepository.  Check your mappings.